# Fortran 90 - Changing the Origin

Tags: arrays, fortran

Here’s what I want to do.

I have a 100 x 100 grid of values, and my original origin is (0,0).  This origin is at the center (hence my array boundaries being at -99:99, etc).  At this origin, I examine its value, as well as the values surrounding that origin.  I have my program read in both horizontal and vertical distances away from the origin, and according to my code, I get a neat set of values organized like this. A person named John had an issue with something like this - so hopefully he can find this!

X = value that isn’t collected.
O = value that is collected.

```
X  X  O  X  X

X  O  O  O  X

O  O  O  O  O

X  O  O  O  X

X  X  O  X  X
```

And depending on my choices for horizontal and vertical distances from the origin, I can do something neat like this:

```
X  X  O  O  O  X  X

X  O  O  O  O  O  X

O  O  O  O  O  O  O

X  O  O  O  O  O  X

X  X  O  O  O  X  X
```

Now, here's the kicker: I don't want my origin to be 0,0 all the time!  I want my program to ask me what my preferred origin is, and then have the program compute accordingly.  This is where I hit a big snag.  Should I write something at the beginning of my code where I've declared my array?  Should I create yet another do loop?  I really want to learn Fortran and doing these kinds of exercises have been very valuable - and I'd love to have some help here.  What am I missing here?

Here's my code so far:

```
!!!!! Declare Variables.
implicit none
integer i, j, k, dist, vdist, row, col, nsum
integer, dimension (-99:99,-99:99) :: values
!!!!!
open(1, file='sampledata.dat')
!!!!! Create a data set from a loop.
do 10 j = -99,99
    do 10 i = -99,99
            values(i,j) = ((j-1) * 2) + (i-3)
10 continue
write(1,*) values
!!!!!
print *, 'Column,Row'
read (*,*) col, row
print *, 'Horizontal Distance From Origin'
read (*,*) dist
print *, 'Vertical Distance From Origin'
read (*,*) vdist
!!!!!
nsum = 0
!!!!!   If the vertical distance is greater than the horizontal distance…
if (vdist .GT. dist) then
do col = -dist, dist
    do row = -vdist + abs(col), vdist - abs(col)
    write (6,*) values(row,col)
    nsum = nsum + values(col,row)
    end do
end do
end if
!!   If the horizontal distance is greater than or equal to the vertical distance…
if (dist .GE. vdist) then
do col = -vdist, vdist
    do row = -dist + abs(col), dist - abs(col)
    write (6,*) values(col,row)
    nsum = nsum + values(col,row)
    end do
end do
end if
!!!!!
print *, nsum
close(1)
end
```

Answer (score 3):

You can place the center of your arrays where ever you want, even deciding at runtime.  Instead of

```
integer, dimension (-99:99,-99:99) :: values
```

use

```
integer, dimension (:, :), allocatable :: values
```

then in the executable part of the code decide the start and end of the array and specify the size of the array at runtime:

```
allocate ( values (start: end, start: end) )
```

Then base the rest of your code on *start* and *end* instead of the fixed values that you are now using.

Comment: Hello,
Thank you!  I see what you are doing.  Just a follow-up question.... when I do:

    allocate ( values (start:end, start: end) )

Should I 'read' in values for 'start' and 'end'?  And should I put the allocate statement behind my first do function?  Or can it be placed anywhere?  I have yet to be introduced to this method so I'm sorry if I sound like a newbie.  Gotta learn sometime!  Thank you again.

Comment: Yes, the array bounds have to be determined before the allocate statement and the array has to be allocated before you use it.

Comment: Hello,
Thank you very much for your help!  It's been working and I'm currently debugging.  
But one quick question, within my do loops, I wish to count the number of elements present in the array.  However, if I use the count or size function, I get the full amount of elements, and not the specific amount of elements computed from within the loop.  

How do I get around this?